# Table has 17 cells, each randomly shows 1 in [A, B, C, ..., M] (13 in total) with equal chance 1/13. Chance of getting at least 3 same letters?

Tags: probability

So I have a list of **13** different letters:

[A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M]

And a table with **17** cells, each cell will randomly show a letter (each letter has an equal probability of being chosen 1/13). **What is the probability that I will see at least 3 matching letters?**

Examples of results with at least 3 matching letters:

[A, A, A, B, B, C, C, D, D, E, E, F, F] - 3 of a kind of A

[A, A, A, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, E, F, F] - 3 of a kind of A and 7 of a kind of B

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us first look at the event that $3$ matching letters **do not** occur and search for its probability.

There are $13^{17}$ different outcomes for the table with equal probability, so the probability connected to a specific outcome is $13^{-17}$

In $\frac{17!}{n_{1}!\times\cdots\times n_{13}!}$ of these outcomes the letter $A$ occurs $n_{1}$ times, letter $B$ occurs $n_{2}$ times, etc.

This with $n_{1}+\cdots+n_{13}=17$.

So defining:

$S=\left\{ \left(n_{1},\ldots,n_{13}\right)\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}\mid n_{1}+\cdots+n_{13}=17\wedge\max\left\{ n_{1},\cdots,n_{13}\right\} \leq2\right\} $

the probability that we are looking for now equals:

$13^{-17}\sum_{\left(n_{1},\ldots,n_{13}\right)\in S}\;\frac{17!}{n_{1}!\times\cdots\times n_{13}!}$

If $\left(n_{1},\ldots,n_{13}\right)\in S$ then some of the $n_{i}$ will equal $2$.

If $k$ denotes the cardinality of $\left\{ i\mid n_{i}=2\right\} $ then $k\in\left\{ 4,5,6,7,8\right\} $.

This leads to $S=S_{4}\cup S_{5}\cup S_{6}\cup S_{7}\cup S_{8}$.

Note that $S_{k}$ contains the elements of $S$ that suffice $n_{1}!\times\cdots\times n_{13}!=2^{k}$.

Possibilities to look at are:

$17=0\times0+9\times1+4\times2$ corresponding with $\frac{13!}{0!9!4!}$ outcomes. Here $n_{1}!\times\cdots\times n_{13}!=2^{4}$

$17=1\times0+7\times1+5\times2$ corresponding with $\frac{13!}{1!7!5!}$ outcomes. Here $n_{1}!\times\cdots\times n_{13}!=2^{5}$

$17=2\times0+5\times1+6\times2$ corresponding with $\frac{13!}{2!5!6!}$ outcomes. Here $n_{1}!\times\cdots\times n_{13}!=2^{6}$

$17=3\times0+3\times1+7\times2$ corresponding with $\frac{13!}{3!3!7!}$ outcomes. Here $n_{1}!\times\cdots\times n_{13}!=2^{7}$

$17=4\times0+1\times1+8\times2$ corresponding with $\frac{13!}{4!1!8!}$ outcomes. Here $n_{1}!\times\cdots\times n_{13}!=2^{8}$

This results in:

$13^{-17}\left(\frac{13!17!}{0!9!4!}\times2^{-4}+\frac{13!17!}{1!7!5!}\times2^{-5}+\frac{13!17!}{2!5!6!}\times2^{-6}+\frac{13!17!}{3!3!7!}\times2^{-7}+\frac{13!17!}{4!1!8!}\times2^{-8}\right)$

**The probability that you will see at least $3$ matching letters is:**

> $1-13^{-17}\left(\frac{13!17!}{0!9!4!}\times2^{-4}+\frac{13!17!}{1!7!5!}\times2^{-5}+\frac{13!17!}{2!5!6!}\times2^{-6}+\frac{13!17!}{3!3!7!}\times2^{-7}+\frac{13!17!}{4!1!8!}\times2^{-8}\right)$

Comment: Doesn't each arrangement have probability $13^{-17}$, not $3^{-17}$? Also, shouldn't you divide by $2^8$, $2^7$ etc. instead of multiplying??

Comment: @ByronSchmuland. Yes off course, you are fully right. Thank you very much for correcting me. Somehow I don't understand how I can make such mistakes and am angry with myself now.

Comment: There's no point in being angry; just correct your mistakes. Now if you change "wich" to "which" I'll stop bugging you! ;)

Comment: @ByronSchmuland. Tibi gratias ago.

Comment: I think you got it correctly. I wrote a Python script to count and the result was similar to yours, around 95%. But I didn't know how to prove it mathematically. Thanks for the detailed explanation.

Comment: It feels good to be confirmed by some script :-). Or maybe my answer is in fact confirming that your script is okay... Well anyhow, I enjoyed solving this.

Answer (score 4):

Think of it this way. What is the probability of not picking out at least 3 matching letters? Picking out 2 or less. So lets do the probability of picking out 2 or less of the same letters and subtract it from the total probability.

What is $P($Choosing '$A$' twice$)$? $P('A'=2)$ is $17C13~(1/13)^2*(12/13)^{11}$ and this is true for every other letter as well. similiary the probability of picking the letter A once is      $17C13~(1/13)*(12/13)^{12}$ and finally the probability of not picking the letter at all         is $17C13~ (12)^{13}$. There are $13$ different ways each of these events can happen since we have 13 different letters.

So the total probability is just $[1-(13 * 17C13* ( (\frac 1{13})^2 * (\frac{12}{13})^{11} + (\frac 1{13}) * (\frac{12}{13})^{12} + (\frac{12}{13})^{13})$. hope this helps!

Comment: To realize that every letter does not occur more than twice the events that you mention must *all* occur (intersection). It seems that you are adding the probabilities (multiplication by $13$) here. That can only make sense if the events are disjoint and it involves a union instead of an intersection.

Comment: @Hamkins Your answer works out to -11915.53762. Does that tell you anything?